# QVideoWidget zooms into upper left until window manually resized - OS X / Qt5.7

Tags: qt, osx-elcapitan

I'm experiencing some strange behavior in what I thought was standard code for playing a video in Qt 5.7. I want the video to start playing immediately, without a play button. When the window appears, about 1 frame of video flashes, but then the view zooms in to the upper left corner of the video. If I resize the window while the video plays, it adjusts to display the full video. If instead of automatically playing the video I add a play button, the video displays correctly once the button is clicked. I do not experience this behavior when using a Scene/GraphicsView/VideoGraphicsItem.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMediaPlayer player;
    player.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("filepath.mp4"));

    QVideoWidget vid;
    player.setVideoOutput(&vid);

    const QRect availableGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(&vid);
    vid.resize(availableGeometry.width() / 6, availableGeometry.height() / 4);
    vid.show();

    player.play();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I'm running OS X 10.11.5, and Qt 5.7.